# Can I export alexa skills kit from Lex V2 console?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

> Hi, I can't find alexa skills kit in the lex V2 portal

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-question-and-answer-bot-with-amazon-lex-and-amazon-alexa/#getting-answers-alexa

Comment: @callmemath this is a link to the AWS QnA Bot solution. It's different than a pure, Lex V2 bot. Exporting from it is also different and will not help with OP's question.